# Where can i get stripe account id for split payments(for application fee)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I found this on internet where can i get `$provideID` for destination parameter. I am using stripe account id https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account found on this url but its showing me

> Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_m9G1T0vzPcd3Ti) No such account: 'acct_****************'

```
$amount = 1000;  // amount in cents
$application_fee = intval($amount * 0.2);  // 20% of the amount

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customerID,
    "destination" => $providerID,
    "application_fee" => $application_fee,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would strongly recommend against directly creating Charges, since this is an old API with many limitations. Instead you should create [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents).

Second, yes it's possible to pass a Stripe account ID when creating a Charge or a PaymentIntent. But that will only work if that account ID is connected to your own Stripe account. And based on the error you shared, I think that's the issue.

So you need to double check that the account ID you are using is listed in your Stripe dashboard here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/connect/accounts/overview